# Fix Bootstrap Navbar to top on scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

1. I have a `div (named=status bar)` at the top of the page with `height = 25px`, `top:0` and `position: fixed`.
2. I want to place a bootstrap `navbar` (with transparent background) `100px` below this status bar.
3. When the page is scrolled, the `navbar` scrolls along and touches the status bar and:
   3.1. gets fixed below the status bar.
   3.2. changes its background color to `red (#ff0000)`.
   3.3. rest of the page scrolls down.
4. When the page is scrolled up, the position of the `navbar` and status bar remains fixed till the scroll reaches almost to the top of the browser.
5. When the top of the browser is reached, the status bar remains at its position as in #1. And the `navbar` scrolls and gets set at a distance of `100px` from the status bar.

**HTML (Status Bar)**

```
<div class="genxcoders-status-bar">     <div class="genxcoders-left genxcoders-fc-white genxcoders-fw-500">
        <span id="genxcoders-date"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="genxcoders-center">
        Support: <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +91-712-606 GENX
    </div>
    <div class="genxcoders-right">
        <ul class="genxcoders-status-bar-social">
            <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></li></a>
            <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
            <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
            <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div> </div>
```

**HTML (Navbar)**

```
<div class="nav-container" id="navigation">
        <div id="genxcoders" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BlueGas</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="/products" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS (Status Bar)**

/* Status Bar */

```
.genxcoders-status-bar {    width: 100%;    height: 25px;       background-color: #1976d2;      position: fixed;    top: 0;     z-index: 9999; }

.genxcoders-status-bar > .genxcoders-left, .genxcoders-status-bar > .genxcoders-center, .genxcoders-status-bar > .genxcoders-right {    width: 33.33%;  height: 25px;   line-height: 25px;      font-size: 12px;        float: left;        text-align: center;     color: #ffffff; }

.genxcoders-status-bar > .genxcoders-right > ul.genxcoders-status-bar-social {  list-style: none;   margin-left:
-30px; } .genxcoders-status-bar > .genxcoders-right > ul.genxcoders-status-bar-social > a > li {    color: #ffffff;     display: inline-block;  margin: auto 10px; }
```

/* Status Bar */

**CSS Navbar**
 /* App Bar */

```
.nav-container {    margin-top:100px;       width: 100%;    height: 50px;
         } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 1); } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default {
    font-size: 15px;
    /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);*/   background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px; } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 1);
    /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);*/   background-color: transparent; } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(3, 169, 244, 1); } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(25, 118, 210, 1); } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #1976d2; } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #1976d2; } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #1976d2; } .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar, .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff; }
```

/* App Bar */

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/sq0kgtn4/1/)**

Comment: Can you please update your code here...

Comment: can you create a code snippet so we can analyze the functional code?

Comment: I could not create the code style, so i used the blockquote to put in the code

Comment: You can insert code by indenting it by 4 spaces. Try providing a jsfiddle or codepen of the working code, too.

Comment: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/sq0kgtn4/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your fiddle, some more serious than others:

- you are loading jQuery over `http://` instead of `https://` and jsFiddle blocks it.
- you are checking `window.scrollTop()` against `#navigation.offset()` but you change `#navigation`s `offset()` using `CSS` and it causes the bar to flicker between states. Compare it to a hard value, like `100px` (which is the margin top of your `#navigation` when it's not fixed, so it works as intended.
- you define `var elementPosition` outside the `scroll()` function, so it doesn't get updated on scroll
- your `.scroll()` function is ***way too heavy***. Just append a class (`fixed`?) to `#navigation` and place all of the CSS inside a `#navigation.fixed { }` declaration, in your `CSS`. I haven't done this last point in the updated fiddle, but I highly recommend it.
- your `CSS` selectors are way too strong. Only use selectors that are strong enough to apply, not stronger. For example, you style your `.navbar-brand` using:

```css
 .nav-container > #genxcoders.navbar-default .navbar-brand {}
```

..., but you only need a selector stronger than

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {}
```

You could just use `#navigation .navbar-brand {}` and, respectively:
`#navigation.fixed .navbar-brand {}`.

Your <kbd>[`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/qLpysoa6/)</kbd>.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a fiddle with all these changes? Coz i wasn't able to comprehend well! Thanks in advance

Comment: If you look closely, the last two words in my answer (*updated fiddle*) are wrapped in an anchor tag (a.k.a link). Feel free to use the pointer device of your choice on it. I just made it a button. Do you see it now?

Comment: as i defined earlier, i want the navbar to be transparent with the active link highlighted. and when navbar gets fixed, i want the background color of the navbar to change to light blue. also, the font color in normal state has to be white the highlighted color dark blue while all other link font color should be #212121. and when the navbar fixes, the font colors should be white. this all happens but when after scrolling and coming back to the normal state, the font color of hightlighted link changes to #212121 and not #ffffff. How do I do that. Also, in fixed state there is no hover effect.

Comment: i did see that, later.

Comment: Your current question is about your navbar not being fixed on scroll and I believe I solved all your problems (quite a few) for doing that. Move you `CSS` in `CSS` and you will have easy control over it. Please note you are not supposed to ask multiple questions into one, especially if they're not directly related.

Comment: part of problem solved. I suppose the problems are related coz all the effects need to take place once the navbar gets fixed, if the navbar is not fixed the effects do not take place.

Comment: @GenXCoders IMHO, your selectors are too strong (specific). You're making it pretty hard on yourself. Just use selectors slightly above Bootstrap's. Only strong enough to apply. You'll see your code gets a lot lighter and a lot more controllable.

Comment: I just updated the answer with an example so you understand what I said about specificity and making it hard on yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141636/discussion-between-genxcoders-and-andrei-gheorghiu).